# Find the sum of a cell from difference worksheets without referencing sheet names

Tags: excel, reference, sum, formula, xlsx

I have a workbook with multiple sheets. All sheet names follow this scheme "Sensor Status", "Sensor Status(1)" and so on. Is there a way to get the SUM of I4 from all these sheets without having to reference each individual sheet name? I tried this however I am getting the ref error. "A5" has the value of "sensor" as I am attempting to use wild cards in the sheet reference of the formula.

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("'*"&A5&"*'!K4"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this for the `Sensor Status(#)`

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("'Sensor Status("&ROW(1:5)&")'!K4"))
```

This is an array formula an must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter.

NOTE: May be able to use SUMPRODUCT instead of SUM to avoid the CSE entry.

But it requires an array, which the `ROW(1:5)` provides.  If this is not ideal then vba or listing the sheets in a column and referring to that would be needed.

See this answer with more options: [How can you sum the same cell across multiple worksheets by worksheet index number in excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59618480/how-can-you-sum-the-same-cell-across-multiple-worksheets-by-worksheet-index-numb/59618840#59618840)

---

You can do a hybrid of vba and formula.

In a module attached to the workbook put:

```
Function SHEETNAME() As Variant
Application.Volatile

Dim temp() As Variant
ReDim temp(1 To Application.Caller.Parent.Parent.Worksheets.Count) As Variant

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To Application.Caller.Parent.Parent.Worksheets.Count
    temp(i) = Worksheets(i).Name
Next

SHEETNAME = temp
End Function
```

This returns all the worksheet names as an array.  Then use something like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A5,SHEETNAME())))*SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&SHEETNAME()&"'!K4"),">0"))
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is also giving me the #REF error :-(

Comment: It will if you do not have sheets named `Sensor Status(...)` where the `...` is a number from 1 to 5.  Also make sure there are not any extra spaces in the actual sheet name.  It works just fine for me.  Try evaluating the formula step by stem and see where it find the error.

Comment: @ThisGuyUsesPowershell see edit for UDF-Function mix.

Answer (score 0):

in VBA:

```
Function SumbyCell(rng As Range) As Double
Dim sum As Double
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
sum = sum + ws.Range(rng.Address).Value2
Next ws
SumbyCell = sum
End Function
```

The function will work without depending on the sheet name.

Call the function by type: `= Sumbycell(I4)`

---

with function:
Suppose you have 2 sheets of names respectively: sheet1, sheet2

Your function is:

```
= CONCAT (SUM (INDIRECT ("sheet" & ROW (1: 2) & "! I4"))))
```

type: ctrl + shift + enter